# Reading data in java form MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I'm writing java code that connects to a database in MySQL. I have a connection but I can't get the data to display in a label in my JFrame. So I'm connected to the database software in my XAMPP database but I can't get the data to display in the label

```
ResultSet rs;
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = null;
int colCount = 0;
String[] colNames = null;

    try {
        rs = engine.executeQuery("select * from music");
        rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        colNames = new String[colCount];
        for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) {
            colNames[i - 1] = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
        }

        String[] currentRow = new String[colCount];// array to hold the
                                                    // row data
        while (rs.next()) { // move the rs pointer on to the next record
                            // (starts before the 1st)
            for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) {
                currentRow[i - 1] = rs.getString(i);
            }
        }

    //System.out.println(authenticated);

    }
    catch (SQLException a)
    {
        System.err.println("SQLException: " + a.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code its working

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;

public class Db {
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws SQLException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname", "root", "");

        java.sql.Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String query = "select * from music";

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

        int columncount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        for(int i = 1 ; i < columncount ; i ++)
            System.out.print(rsmd.getColumnName(i));

        System.out.println();

        while (rs.next()) {

            for(int i = 1 ; i < columncount ; i ++)
            {
                System.out.print(rs.getString(i));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        conn.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Could tell what exactly I could use since I have a separate class for the SQLEngine so it's not all in the one class.

Comment: package softwareDesign;

    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    public class MySQLEngine {
    Connection conn;
    String dbName = "software";
 String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
 String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
 String username = "root";
 String password = "";
 
 public MySQLEngine(String username, String password){
  conn = null;
  this.username=username;
  this.password=password;
 }
//first part

Comment: public void connect(){
  try{
   Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, username, password);
   System.out.println("Made a connection");
   
   //conn.close();
  }
  catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println("Haven't made a connection");
  }
 }
 
 public ResultSet executeQuery(String sqlStatement) throws SQLException{
  ResultSet rs = null;
  
  try{
   Statement s = conn.createStatement();
   rs = s.executeQuery(sqlStatement);
  }
  
  catch(SQLException e){
   throw e;
  }
  return rs;
 }
}//second part

Comment: This is the class MySQLEngine that is where the connection to the database s established

Comment: public void connect() {
  try {
   Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
   conn = DriverManager
     .getConnection(url + dbName, username, password);
   System.out.println("Made a connection");
   
   executeQuery("what so ever your query");
   
   conn.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Haven't made a connection");
  }
 }

Comment: try this call the executequery method from connection class that will execute your query properly

Comment: @user2961276 Please edit your question and do not post code in comments

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to have separate class for DB connection and use this connection somewhere else you could do something like this.

```
public class SQLConnect {
    public static Connection ConnectDb() {
        try { 
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = null;
            try {
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/databasename", "root", "");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SQLConnect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            return conn;
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("not connected");
            e.printStackTrace();//print extra info if error is thrown
            return null; 
        }
    }
}
```

And use this class as follows

```
Connection conn = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;

try {
    conn = SQLConnect.ConnectDb();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM somedatabase WHERE somevalue = ? ";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, CriminalID);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();

    if(rs.next()) {
        /*
         * set values of labels to those from database
         */
         jLabel.setText(rs.getString("Column name"));
    }
```

this will get you data from database where some value is equal to whatever you specify